# Add 1 to an integer represented as an array of digits

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, array

**Problem Statement**

This is another LeetCode question I came across, where I need to add 1 to a number.

The number is represented as an integer array where each index position is a digit and therefore a number from 0-9. There are no leading zeros except for the number 0 itself.
The index position 0, that is arr[0] represents the MSB and the index position n-1, that is
arr[n-1] represents the LSB.

Thus, we need to add one to the LSB and return the number as an integer array. Here is the code which I wrote (it got accepted, passed all test cases) :

```
class Solution
{
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits)
    {
        int carry = 0,
        len = digits.length;

        int i = len - 1;

        if (len == 0)
            return digits;

        if (len == 1 && digits[0] < 9)
        {
            digits[0] += 1;
            return digits;
        }

        if (len == 1 && digits[0] == 9)
        {
            digits[0] = 0;
            digits = resize(digits, 2);
            return digits;
        }

        do
        {
            digits[i] += 1;

            if (digits[i] == 10)
            {
                digits[i] = 0;
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
                return digits;
            }

            i--;
        } 
        while (carry == 1 && i > -1);

        if (carry == 1)
        {
            digits = resize(digits, len + 1);
            carry = 0;
        }  

        return digits;
    }
    private int[]  resize(int[] arr, int size)
    {
        int[] copy = new int[size];
        int i;

        copy[0] = 1;

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
            copy[i] = arr[i-1];

        return copy;
    }
}
```

**Analysis**

- *Running Time : O(n) in the worst case*
- *Total Space  : O(n) in the worst case*
- *Worst Case   : When adding 1 to a m-digit number results in an (m+1) digit number

  (eg. 999 + 1 = 1000)*

**Questions**

- Is there a better way to solve this problem? (I mean, a different but more efficient algorithm than mine)
  *I got a performance of only 29% with this solution no matter how many times I submitted the code, so definitely my algorithm is inefficient*
- Instead of using a resizing array, should I be using an array list if I want better performance?
  *Can ArrayList handle the overflow condition better than resizing array?*
- Should I be using the resizing array technique at all?
  *Is it less efficient?*
- Is O(n) the best possible running time for the problem?
  *I don't see how we can do it O(log n) or less.*

**Further Notes**

- Here is a link to the Github repository which has the above code with more comments: [PlusOne.java](https://github.com/enigma6174/leetcode-array/blob/438670e7b128438c428227e71318c210613dfd60/PlusOne.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simpler implementation**

You can simplify a lot the iteration through the digits. Resizing with an `ArrayList` would definitely be worse, as it's simply a wrapper of an array and you would need to box/unbox the `int`s to `Integer`.

This uses the same algorithm, but with less instructions and it will therefore be a bit faster:

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
  int len = digits.length;
  if (len == 0)
    return digits;

  for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (digits[i] == 9) {
      digits[i] = 0;
    } else {
      digits[i]++;
      return digits;
    }
  }

  return newArray(len + 1);
}
```

**New array**

In the case where we create a new array, we know that it will be filled by a `1` followed by all zeros. Since in Java all variables not explicitly initialized have their default values (`0` in case of `int`), we can simply do:

```
private int[] newArray(int size) {
  int[] arr = new int[size];
  arr[0] = 1;
  return arr;
}
```

This will save us one read and one write for every position.

**Benchmark**

I did a test with JMH, comparing both solutions.

Parameters:

```
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
```

Input data sets:

- "mixed": Starts with `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`, and gets increased in every iteration;
- "10000x9": It's an array composed of 10 000 '9's, like `{9, 9, 9, 9, ...}`. This is reset back to all-9s in every iteration.

Results:

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
Test.fill              avgt    5   1852.195 ▒ 101.178  ns/op
Test.new_10000x9       avgt    5   8793.836 ▒ 176.757  ns/op
Test.new_mix           avgt    5      3.957 ▒   0.040  ns/op
Test.original_10000x9  avgt    5  15761.188 ▒  46.132  ns/op
Test.original_mix      avgt    5      4.209 ▒   0.026  ns/op
```

The `fill` test case was just to figure out the approximate overhead of resetting the array to 9's in the `10000x9` tests. If we remove that time from the results of the `10000x9` test cases, we see that the new implementation is about twice as fast.

Comment: One improvement: there's no need to pass the old digits `arr` to the `resize()` method.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it. In fact `resize` is now misleading, I renamed it.

Comment: @DuarteMeneses thanks so much for the enlightenment! While your code also performed at around 30% on LeetCode (which is not a matter of concern in any way), what I loved about your solution was it's simplicity and elegance. The way you showed me how to modify the array length by avoiding unnecessary read/write was truly awesome! Thank you so much! :)